# Play framework input without label

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've just started with Play Framework and I'm looking to create input field in scala template but without label and for some reason I'm unable to get rid of the generated label element. Here is how my code looks like :

```
@helper.inputText(form("name"), 'id -> "name", 'class -> "ui-state-default", 'autocomplete -> "off", 'placeholder -> "Please write name ...")
```

So I end up with this element along with my input (looking at browser source code) :

```
<dt><label for="s2id_autogen2">name</label></dt>
```

Is there any way of removing it?

Comment: see also the official `Play framework API` for `input type="text"` (watch out for the framework version) https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.3/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputText$

Answer (score 22):

My solution was :

```
@helper.inputText(form("name"), 
    'id -> "name",
    'class -> "ui-state-default",
    'autocomplete -> "off",
    'placeholder -> "Please write name ...",
    '_label -> null
)
```

Comment: I did the same thing and I have a null pointer exception at the line of the declaration of the field. Do you know where it could com from ? Thanks

Comment: I found the solution myself, you have to define `_label` as null and not `label`. I edited your answer ;)

Comment: This leaves the label element in the DOM

Comment: in my project (we're using bootstrap) I was able to set `'_showLabel` to `false`

Answer (score 7):

I guess you would need to write your own field constructor, eg:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

More info here:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the label being in the generated source, you can generate an empty label by setting `'_label -> ""`  If you don't want it in the DOM at all, you'll need to create a field constructor or hand generate the fields.